# Naming a function in a paper

Tags: functions, notation

I'm writing a paper (in physics), and I want use the same name for two related functions that have different domains.  Please allow me to elaborate.

I have function $f: R\longmapsto R$.  I want to define a second function on the set of 2-tuples $f:R\times R \longmapsto R$ where f(x,x) = f(x)f(x).   Here is my question: Can I use the same name for the two functions?  In the context of this paper, it would reduce the amount of notation if I could give these two functions the same name. I would argue that there is no confusion here, because the two functions have different domains.  So from the usage of the function, and the domain, a reader will always know which function being is referring to.  Please comment.  thanks.

Comment: It is better to use some notation like e.g. $\hat f$. Similar, but different..

Comment: It is better if you define $g: R\times R \longmapsto R$ as $g(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$. Don't use $g(x,x)$. It implies that $g$ is defined only on $2-$ tuples which has same coordinates.

Comment: It seems to me that what matters is whether your notation would seem clear and understandable to a _physicist_. Acceptability to a _mathematician_ would seem a secondary concern. Perhaps you should ask on the Physics stackexchange.

Comment: They aren't very friendly at Physics stackexchange

Comment: I agree with Mathi, $f(x) f(y)$ is clearer. However, in my opinion, it's fine to use $f$ for both functions, because the two functions are so closely related. It would be a different story if, in addition to having different domains, the two functions' definitions were independent of each other. But I'm barely a mathematician and I'm definitely not a physicist by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon to use the same symbol when you restrict or enlarge the domain of a function, but that's not what you're doing here.  Your function of two variables is not necessarily *ever* equal to the function of one variable:  $f(x)$ might always be negative and $f(x,y)$ always positive.  How would it look, notation-wise, if you used $F(x,y)$ for the two-variable function?